# Слот с параметром

Tags: python, события, qt, pyqt4

Здравствуйте. Вопрос связан со слотами в PyQt4 Как можно сделать слот в который я буду передавать параметр? Я делаю вот так, без параметра.

```
self.connect(SignFile, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.FileDialog);

def FileDialog(self):
    NamePath = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 'C:\\');
    if NamePath == '':
        messbox = QtGui.QMessageBox;
        messbox.about(self, 'Error', 'Unknown path...');
        messbox.resize(200);
    else:
        self.path = NamePath;
```

Меня интересует, как можно вызвать слот FileDialog, при условии что я в него добавлю параметр

```
def FileDialog(self, textbox)
```

Потому, что если я укажу там скобочки:

```
self.connect(SignFile, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.FileDialog(textboxobject));
```

тогда при инициализации приложения, будет запускаться диалоговое окно. 
Извините, если вопрос глупый, я только начал разбираться в PyQt4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короткий пример, который покажет все

```
self.connect(self.slider, qt.SIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), lcd, qt.SLOT("display(int)"))

def display(self, value):
    print (value)

self.emit(qt.PYSIGNAL("valueChanged(int)"), (0, ))
```

Comment: спасибо, испробую)